# is it possible to configure testlink to allow connections to jira per user?

Tags: jira, testlink

I was just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to configure testlink to create connections to Jira in a per user basis?  I have been able to configure access for one user but I would like to be able to generate a different connection for each testlink user so that if bugs are created they would be shown to have been so by the correct Jira user.

Thanks in Advance,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the username/password for Testlink the same as JIRA can allow saving the username and password as session variable and using them as the input for the configuration in jirasoapInterface.class.php may help.

We have done this for our system to allow issue creation by a logged in user.

Hope this idea helps
Cheers
Sriparna

Answer (score 0):

available for redmine and mantis on 1.9.12. May be using these code as example you can do development for JIRA